# How to prevent user interaction during screen transition animation?

Tags: react-native, transition, stack-navigator

When navigating between screens using the `StackNavigator` with a `fade` transition, a user is able to click during the transition animation and possibly hit a `TouchableOpacity` on the screen that is being navigated away from. The `TouchableOpacity` registers the hit and thus the app responds accordingly. This is causing issues for "fast clicking" users where they click a button to navigate to a new screen and immediately click where they think a new button will be, but in reality is clicking a button on the previous screen.

Is there a way to prevent any user interaction during these transition animations? I have tried setting the transition duration to 0 like so:

```
transitionConfig: () => ({
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 0
    }
})
```

but the issue still occurs.

I do not want to disable the animation completely, because it is quick enough for most users and they like the animation.

Answer (score 1):

So in your case you can do several things

- You can use React Native Activity Indicator -> View
- You can use Overlay Library -> react-native-loading-spinner-overlay -> View GitHub
- If you like to make loading like facebook / instagram -> then use react-native-easy-content-loader -> View GitHub

Answer (score 0):

you need to flag screen before navigating away; disabling all touchs.

an easy way would be to have a reusable hook that return a transparent absolute positioned View that cover entier page and a callback to enable it;

so you flow will be; enable this which will overlap whole screen and capture any clicks basically disabling them;

something more like:

```
function useOverlay(){
 const [isVisible, toggle] = React.useState(false);
 const Component = React.memo(()=><View style={styles.transparentAbsolute} />,[])


  return [toggle, isVisible ? Component : null];
}
```

then inside your Screen before you call `navigate` just call toggle

and include Component at top of you screen;

```
export default function TabOneScreen({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<'TabOne'>) {
  const [ toggle, component ]  = useOverlay();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {component}
      <Button onPress={()=>{toggle(true); navigation.navigate('Home');} title="go home" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This would have to be done for each screen using this transition correct? Because I have many components/screens using the navigation service.

Comment: mainly in root pages yes; you can simplify implementation more by instead of manually trigger overlay before navigation, you can listen for navigation event and use Component on root screen only;

Comment: well, if you use recent version of react-navigation, you can also pass a key to prevent double via providing a unique key when you call `navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'RouteName', key: 'unique-route' })` @pfinferno

Comment: Has someone tried to hook the the overlay to navigation events with success?